# Suppress running messages from RStan in Rmarkdown HTML output

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, stan

The following are my r code.

````
```{r message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, cache=0,eval=TRUE, error=FALSE}
stan_m1 <- rethinking::map2stan(
  alist(
    y ~ dbinom(n, p),
    logit(p) <- alpha + bP*P + bA*A + bV*V,
    alpha ~ dnorm(0, 10),
    bP ~ dnorm(0, 5),
    bA ~ dnorm(0, 5),
    bV ~ dnorm(0, 5)
  ),
  data = d1, chains=2 , iter=2500 , warmup=500, debug=FALSE , 
  verbose=FALSE,refresh=-1
)
````

When I `knit` my `rmarkdown` file as html output, I am getting following output. Is there any way to turn off these messages?

[image: R-Output]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Put `results="hide"` in your chunk header.

And, in **rstan** 2.18.2 or later you can specify the `refresh = 0` argument to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Oh the pain I suffered until I stumbled upon this answer! Thank you.