# How to prevent opening /tmp files with knitr using nvim-r and rstan

Tags: r, knitr, neovim, rstan

I'm using R in neovim with nvim-r to knit Rmd documents using the `\kh` or `\kp` commands. The problem is when I knit an Rmd that fits an Rstan model, it prints the output of the Rstan `sampling()` call including the progress of the chains in a separate, temporary file at this location:

> file:///tmp/RtmpMmXreV/file27067eb3452f_StanProgress.html

that contains this output:

> Click the Refresh button to see progress of the chains
>   starting worker pid=17045 on localhost:11515 at 14:31:54.447
>   starting worker pid=17070 on localhost:11515 at 14:31:54.670

and it opens that html file in my browser. The result is that my browser keeps popping open every time a new model starts sampling. This only happens when I parallelize the chains using `options(mc.cores = parallel::detectCores())`. The html files do not pop open without that command.

Is it possible to prevent nvim-r from opening these temporary html files or is it possible to silence the chain output from Rstan?

Minimal example:

```
library(rstan)

options(mc.cores = parallel::detectCores())

data(DNase)

model <- stan_model(model_code = "
data {
    int n;
    vector[n] conc;
    vector[n] density;
}
parameters {
    real b0;
    real b1;
    real<lower=0> sigma;
}
model {
    conc ~ normal(b0 + b1 * (density), sigma);
    b0 ~ normal(0, 10);
    b1 ~ normal(0, 10);
    sigma ~ normal(0, 10);
}")

fit <- sampling(model, data = list(n = nrow(DNase),
                       conc = DNase$conc, 
                       density = DNase$density))
```

EDIT:
I've tried adding `results="hide"` to the chunk header and `refresh = 0` to the `sampling()` call based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47104377/suppress-running-messages-from-rstan-in-rmarkdown-html-output) to no avail. `refresh = 0` does succeed in removing the `starting worker...` part of the message, but it still opens an html file that says `Click the Refresh button to see progress of the chains`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `open_progress = FALSE` to `sampling()` prevents stan from saving the progress of the chains to a log file. The default, `open_progress = TRUE` only takes effect when `cores > 1`. From the [rstan reference](https://mc-stan.org/rstan/reference/stanmodel-method-sampling.html). Example:

`sampling(model, open_progress = FALSE)`